# paramiko allows sftp connection without key

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko

I was running the demo_sftp.py file from the demo folder in the [paramiko github](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/tree/master/demos). I was stepping through it in PyDev and expected to get an error because I didn't have a key to the server I was trying to connect to but I got the print statement saying that the script couldn't open the host key file and then it went ahead and did the get and put.

Here's a code snippet.

```
try:
    host_keys = paramiko.util.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/known_hosts'))
except IOError:
    try:
        # try ~/ssh/ too, because windows can't have a folder named ~/.ssh/
        host_keys = paramiko.util.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser('~/ssh/known_hosts'))
    except IOError:
        print '*** Unable to open host keys file'
        host_keys = {}

if host_keys.has_key(hostname):
    hostkeytype = host_keys[hostname].keys()[0]
    hostkey = host_keys[hostname][hostkeytype]
    print 'Using host key of type %s' % hostkeytype


# now, connect and use paramiko Transport to negotiate SSH2 across the connection
try:
    t = paramiko.Transport((hostname, port))
    t.connect(username=username, password=password, hostkey=hostkey)
    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)

    # dirlist on remote host
    dirlist = sftp.listdir('.')
    print "Dirlist:", dirlist
```

I really expected it to go to the except on the t.connect line because hostkey is NoneType.

When I open an ssh connection with

```
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    try:
        ssh.connect('.'.join([self.name, self.domain]),
                    username=self.username, password=self.password)
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("ps aux | grep Xvnc | wc -l")
```

I have to have the AutoAddPolicy() line or it fails. So what's the difference? Obviously I'm just learning this but I thought that sftp would be just as strict as ssh.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is an acceptable practice.

Comment from Transport.connect

```
'''
Negotiate an SSH2 session, and optionally verify the server's host key
and authenticate using a password or private key.  This is a shortcut
for L{start_client}, L{get_remote_server_key}, and
L{Transport.auth_password} or L{Transport.auth_publickey}.  Use those
methods if you want more control.

You can use this method immediately after creating a Transport to
negotiate encryption with a server.  If it fails, an exception will be
thrown.  On success, the method will return cleanly, and an encrypted
session exists.  You may immediately call L{open_channel} or
L{open_session} to get a L{Channel} object, which is used for data
transfer.

@note: If you fail to supply a password or private key, this method may
succeed, but a subsequent L{open_channel} or L{open_session} call may
fail because you haven't authenticated yet.
'''
```

Comment from SSHClient.connect

```
'''
Connect to an SSH server and authenticate to it.  The server's host key
is checked against the system host keys (see L{load_system_host_keys})
and any local host keys (L{load_host_keys}).  If the server's hostname
is not found in either set of host keys, the missing host key policy
is used (see L{set_missing_host_key_policy}).  The default policy is
to reject the key and raise an L{SSHException}.
'''
```

Maybe it is due to the fact that sftp can only transport data while ssh can run terminal commands. I do find it interesting that a man-in-the-middle attack doesn't seem to be a concern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below syntax

```
    import pysftp
    cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
    cnopts.hostkeys = None
    with pysftp.Connection(hostname, port=port, username=user_id, password=password,
                           cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
        with sftp.cd(self.directory):  # temporarily chdir to public
            sftp.put(filepath)
```